# Cannot "step into" another subprogram while debugging with the Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

To debug with the Oracle SQL Developer, I first perform "compile for debug" and then start debugging. However, even if I use another subprogram within my code, which also is a subprogram of the same user I'm connected to, it basically performs step over instead of step into.

Why that might be? And how can overcome that problem?

Comment: Make sure that program is also compiled for debug AND you have a breakpoint in it